# dbms_output.put_line in PLSQL Developer fails with ORA-06502 for strings longer than 32512 chars

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper, dbms-output

This script fails in PLSQL Developer version 14.0.0.1961 (error `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small`):

```sql
declare
  v varchar2(32767) := rpad('x',32513,'x');
begin
  dbms_output.enable(null);
  dbms_output.put_line(v);
end;
/
```

- If 32513 is replaced by higher value, it fails too.
- If 32513 is replaced by lower value, it works (i.e. prints text without failure).
- In SQL*Plus and Toad it works for up to 32767 (this is expected).
- In Intellij Idea it works for up to 32766, for 32767 it does not raise exception though prints nothing.

How can I explain such behaviour? The 32512 seems to be interesting constant (I found it in some [APEX question](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/966248/clob-datatype-usage), [question about blobs](https://codeverge.com/asp.net.oracle/inserting-blob-data-of-size-more-than-32512-ch/46484) and is also mentioned in [JDBC tutorial](https://web.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10gR2/java.102/b14355/overvw.htm) but I miss any connection to described problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a PL/SQL Developer bug.

In 2013, they said they'll [fix it](https://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=45723):

> it's a bit of a low-level issue, so his may need to wait until version 11.0.

Which version do you use?

Comment: 14.0.0.1961 (I updated question), anyway thanks for link, I didn't found it

Comment: You're welcome. Sadly, they still didn't fix it. Too low-level issue, eh?